# Use of search patterns with monger

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I wish to access a mongo db from clojure using search patterns like this:

```
find({Keywords: /search-pattern/})
```

I have a database called "soulflyer", containing an "images" collection and each member has a "Keywords" field containing an array of exif keywords from the image it represents. 
To search for images of myself from the mongo java shell I do this:

```
db.getCollection('images').find({Keywords: "Iain Wood"})
```

and I get back a list of all the entries that contain the Keyword "Iain Wood". This also works fine in clojure, if I do this in the repl:

```
(def connection (mg/connect))
(def db (mg/get-db connection "soulflyer"))
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" "Iain Wood"}))
```

However, I want to search for partial matches on keywords. This works ok from the java shell with a command like this:

```
db.getCollection('images').find({Keywords: /Iain/})
```

As expected, I get back all the images with a keyword that contains "Iain". However I can't find how to make this work from clojure.

```
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" "/Iain/"}))
```

returns an empty list

```
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" /Iain/}))
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" '/Iain/'}))
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" \/Iain\/}))
(seq (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" "\/Iain\/"}))
```

give me a LispReader$ReaderException or freeze up the repl.

How do I get clojure/monger to search on a simple pattern match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that monger supports this substring pattern match out of the box, but you can easily use regular expressions. This is documented in [mongers query documentation](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/querying.html). You need to use the `$regex` operator. Something like the following should work:

```
  (mc/find db "images" {"Keywords" {$regex ".*Iain.*"}})
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I had hoped to use the simpler more elegant pattern match syntax, but regex will do the job...